# Bash command substitution and variable issue

Tags: command-line, bash, openssh

I am writing some simple backup utility in bash and any output must be in JSON.

I am checking for host reachability and if any error occurs, I want to print it out. However, I have an issue with output:

```
FAILED=1
TIME_STARTED=$(date +%s)
OUT="$( ${SSH} ${SSH_ARGS} ${HOST} 'true' 2>&1 >/dev/null)"

if [[ $? != 0 && ! -z "${OUT}" ]]; then

    TIME_ENDED=$(date +%s)
    JSON="{ \"time_started\": \"${TIME_STARTED}\", \"time_ended\": \"${TIME_ENDED}\", \"state\": ${FAILED}, \"error\": \"${OUT}\" }"
    echo "${JSON}"    
    exit ${TRUE}
fi
```

results in:

```
[root@internal ~]# ./backup -H 17.17.0.111
" }time_started": "1394889912", "time_ended": "1394889913", "state": 1, "error": "Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
[root@internal]#
```

I am using some node.js CLI utils to pretty print JSON for final output, but it fails because it gets invalid JSON from the shell. How should I fix this?

P.S: I know that there are plenty of libraries to format JSON, but I need to do this way and I would like to not discuss it here.

Comment: What OS are you using (bash can be installed on pretty much all of them)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the ssh output is picking up a carriage return character. Try:

```
JSON="{ \"time_started\": \"${TIME_STARTED}\", \"time_ended\": \"${TIME_ENDED}\", \"state\": ${FAILED}, \"error\": \"${OUT%$'\r'}\" }"
```

Explanation: This:

```
${OUT%$'\r'}
```

cuts of a trailing CR character if there is one...

Comment: Of course, the JSON is probably wrong _as well_, given that those timestamps are strings.